# capture mouse wheel event even if mouse is not over focused control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use a number of scrolling controls(each control is a user control).now mouse wheel works if mouse is over the focused control How can I achieve when  the mouse wheel is spun, the control with focus receives the input no matter to what control the mouse cursor is over.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WINAPI function called SetWindowsHookEx. You can find that function in User32.dll.